# How to fetch and make calculations with sqlite data in python?

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I want to fetch the data in a specific row and be able to perform calculations with it, so far I have this:

```
import sqlite3 as lite
con=con.connect(mydatabase.db)
cur=con.cursor()
query=cur.execute("SELECT price from items where ID=1")
print(cur.fetchone())
```

which returns

```
(13.5,)
```

I can't make any calculations with that. I decided I would just treat the fetchone() method as a tuple and came up with this:

```
cur.fetchone()[0]
```

which returns

```
13.5
```

I can work with that, but I think it is a dirty solution is there any other way to fetch the data? 
I've also tried

```
for row in cur.fetchall():
   print(row[0])
```

which returns a real number I can work with, but I don't know why this works.

```
13.5
```

A number I can work with. I don't know which of the 2 solutions is better, or if there is something more efficient. Could you also give me a brief explanation of the fetch objects I find them somewhat confusing. Thanks your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: you do know sqlite can do some calculations right (usually people do them in python but you can do some on sqlite queries directly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not dirty. That's how low level sql with Python works. Tuple represents columns (in order defined in `select` statement, keep in mind that you should not use `select *` cause there's no guarantee in what order you will receive the data). Thus `cur.fetchone()[0]` is absolutely fine (as long as `price` is first in `select` query).

On the other hand `fetchall` returns a list of all rows that satisfy the query. So the result of calling `fetchall` is **always** a list of tuples. It might be an empty list though. Basically `fetchone` does the same thing as `fetchall` except it gets the next row from `fetchall` (thus multiple calls to `fetchone` will get you all rows in `fetchall`). Note that `fetchone` will return `None` if there is no more data.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you think it's dirty. One point, though: you say you're treating the method as a tuple, but that's obviously not right: the method *returns* a tuple. And that's fine: you just access the first element of it with `[0]`, as you would any other tuple. There's no need for any extra loops.